# GLOBALS array changes element values after data is posted through Ajax

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have login page in my system when I post a JSON object of `email_id` and `password` through ajax request, and accept it with `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);`
But it changes my GLOBALS configuration of the project. This is how i have set the config.php file :

```
$GLOBALS['user'] = $configuration['database']['username'];
$GLOBALS['password'] = $configuration['database']['password'];
$GLOBALS['dbname'] = $configuration['database']['database'];
$GLOBALS['host'] = $configuration['database']['hostname'];
```

So if I have database password as `abc` ; the posted user password replaces it and connection to database fails.
Can anyone tell me how or why it happens?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more code on how you are accessing the data from the ajax call. Also the JS for how you make the ajax call.

Comment: Also, if you have your database config in that initial configuration variable, why not just use that instead of assigning them all to globals like that?

Comment: @IncredibleHat I am working on a maintenance project so I can't change the previously written code.
btw thanks for writing, I got the answer.

Comment: I referred this : http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php